Custom cypress run does not fail the github actions job when artifacts are added
I am trying to execute the cypress in the GitHub action, I am not using any Action from the marketplace.
When I remove the artifacts part out the execution is working as intended. That is it fails the pipeline on test failure.
But when artifacts are added it does not fails the pipeline even if the tests fails. Tried with continue-on-error: false. etc

name: Run e2e Test cases
run: |
cd cypress-sdet
npm install --include=dev
npm run cypress:run
continue-on-error: false
- name: Slack Notification
  uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
  with:
    status: ${{ job.status }}
    fields: workflow,job,commit,repo,ref,author,took,result
    custom_payload: |
      {
        text: "${{ github.workflow }}: ${{ github.repository }} (${{ github.sha }}) by ${{ github.actor }} (${{ steps.cypress.outcome }})",
      }
  if: always() # Pick up events even if the job fails or is canceled.

- name: Upload build artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: cypress-sdet/cypress/reports/mocha/output.json
  if: always()



Expecting the pipeline should fail when test fails. but artifacts should be generated in both the cases.

It looks like the step with if: always() clears the failure flag. You could add a completion step that reports workflow failed status.
  # Capture the failure status in an environment variable
  - name: Set Failure Flag
    if: failure()
    run: echo "TEST_FAILED=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: Always run
    if: always()
    run: echo "Always run."

  - name: Fail the workflow if tests failed
    if: env.TEST_FAILED == 'true'
    run: exit 1

